# Capital gains tax with reverse order of purchase and sale

Tags: united-states, capital-gains-tax, capital-gain

In the US, is it in principle allowed to compute a capital gain/loss by reversing the order of purchase and sale?
Here is an example:
Assume, on day 1 you buy 1 unit of an asset for 100 dollars. 60 days later, you sell that 1 units of that asset for 200 dollars. 60 days later yet, you buy 1 unit of that asset again for 300 dollars.
It seems you would have made a short term capital gain of 100 dollars, and the basis for the asset you hold is 300. Is it legal to claim a short term loss of 100 (allocating the purchase for 300 to the sale), and assigning a basis of 100 to the asset that is still held?

EDIT: It seems "obvious" the answer is no, but can we point to any authoritative reference to confirm that? The answer is not obvious because in a short sale of an asset a purchase is matched with an earlier sale by definition.

Comment: I didn’t downvote you but you sold for a gain then rebought.  That doesn’t need an authoritative source, that’s just reality.  Why would you get to top up tour cost basis as though you had a loss?  A lot of other things probably also went up, if I thought about buying one of those should I get to adjust my cost basis as though my not-buying should be considered a loss?

Comment: The authoritative source for determining capital gains is the IRS: "How do I figure the cost basis when the shares I'm selling were purchased at various times and at different prices?"  Answer: "When selling securities, you should be able to identify the specific shares you are selling." YOU CANNOT IDENTIFY WHAT YOU DO NOT OWN and at the time of your sale of shares, YOU DID NOT OWN THE SECOND LOT OF SHARES PURCHASED. That's reality, no matter how many times you say it's otherwise.

Comment: Generally speaking, laws work based on reality, not on fiction. There are a lot of places where US tax law _does_ work based on fiction, but only where the law specifically says so. You can't just make up your own fiction and claim that your fiction is permitted because there's no law prohibiting it.

Answer (score 0):

FIFO stands for First In, First Out.
LIFO stands for Last In, First Out.

At the time of the sale, you can designate what shares you want sold (FIFO, LIFO or other shares). The IRS requires that your broker verifies that the specific shares that are sold. Without that confirmation, your broker will default to FIFO (First In, First Out).

Assume 100 share purchases and sales:

In your example, you had no opportunity to designate which shares were to be sold because you only owned 100 shares at the time that  you sold 100 shares.

If you had purchased 100 shares at $100 and then another 100 shares at $300 and then sold 100 shares at $200 then you could have designated which lot to sell.

Comment: This does not answer my question. I just used "stocks" as a placeholder. I am interested in the case where there is no broker and therefore nothing has been reported to the IRS, i.e. the case where there is a list of trades for which cap gains have to be computed. The question is, is it explicitly disallowed by the IRS to claim a security that was held at time t, was borrowed from oneself, sold at t+60, and then re-purchased at t+120, so that the final purchase is matched with the earlier sale.

Comment: You didn't "borrow it from yourself". You sold it. Then you re-bought it.

Comment: (1) You cannot borrow stock from yourself. (2)There is no such thing in the US as stocks as a "placeholder" (3) Your comment of "there is no broker and therefore nothing has been reported to the IRS, i.e. the case where there is a list of trades for which cap gains have to be computed" makes absolutely no sense (4) I don't understand what's so difficult for you to understand. You cannot sell what you do not own unless you are borrowing stock from a counter party and shorting it... and that's clearly not the case because of your own words: "Note that this is not a question about a short sale."

Comment: You are taking everything to literal. Not all assets are stocks or tradable via brokers. For example, if you buy a an expensive watch from someone and later sell it for twice the money you owe capital gains tax on the profit, and nothing has been reported to the IRS at the time the tax return is filed. I didn't say you can "borrow stock from yourself", I was giving an example as to how one could justify allocating the purchase to a sale in reverse order. The question is *where does it explicitly disallow this* (not borrowing from oneself, but the reverse allocation)

Comment: @braaterAfrikaaner Imagine asking for an explicit statement that 51374 + 23212 == 74586. It follows directly from the definition of integer addition. Likewise, your situation is entirely explained by the common definitions of ownership, sales, and capital gains. Just because you would like there to be an exception doesn't mean anyone has ever felt the need to explicitly state that such an exception does not exist.

Comment: @chepner, I am asking a general question, I don't "want there" to be anything. you are incorrect in your assertion that the answer to my questions follow from definitions, at least I could not find it. A capital gain is defined by the IRS as difference of what you received from a sale and what you paid for, it does not specify that the sale has to happen after the purchase (if it did, how would you calculate cap gain on Short Sales?)

Comment: @braaterAfrikaaner - Tom:  "Would you like to buy my house on the Riviera for half price?" Dick: "I sure would like that!  It's a great deal! I can save a bundle.  When can I see your house?" Tom: "I don't own a house but it's a really good deal!!!" The lesson for you?  Don't confuse the actual facts with some fantasy of would like them to be.

Comment: @Bob Baerker, your comments are not helpful. You making fun of my question because the answer seems obvious, but it isn't. In a short sale, one borrows an asset (from someone else) and buys it back later. To determine capital gains one *has to* use the basis from the purchase that happened after the sale. That is the reason why the IRS cannot specify that the purchase has to happen before the sale. If it doesn't specify it, it's not outrageous to assume one can always do it.

Comment: @Bob Baerker, Also, it's not a good look if you try to make fun of someone and inadvertently advertise your own ignorance in the process. Assets that the seller doesn't own are being sold all the time, its called... a short sale. Maybe don't attempt to answer questions here that are above your pay grade.

Comment: And short sales are *explicitly* defined because they create an exception to the obvious conclusion that you cannot sell something you don't own. No such exception exists for claiming a loss just because you decided to open a new position after closing an old position for a gain; what answer would you expect to receive if no such explicit statement of this fact exists? Do you just want your question open forever with no answer, or are you willing to accept the fact that it is not legal, and its illegality is adequately implied by existing regulations?

Comment: Unless someone actually *tries* to do this, goes to court, and a judge writes an opinion confirming the obvious interpretation of existing law, no such "authoratative reference" is likely to ever be created.

Comment: @braaterAfrikaaner the issue here is that reported and not reported to the IRS doesn’t make a difference for your tax liability.  If you sell a watch at a profit, yes you may technically owe capital gain tax but (iirc there’s a hobby exclusion of a few thousand) most people would simply deal with that gain by choosing to forget to report it, which isn’t legal. To your point, none of this is specific to stock, but you can’t borrow something from yourself.  You could maybe have a Corp borrow something from you (but I’m sure there are self dealing regs if you’re the only shareholder of the Corp).

Comment: FWIW the IRS has special rules for what happens if you do actually do a short sale of things you separately own, see the [Constructive Sale Rule](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/constructivesalerule.asp). But that's still only relevant if that's what you actually did.

Comment: @chepner, I am not asking whether an exceptions exist. For what I suggest to be illegal, it is a necessary condition that the IRS *disallows* it. That's different from the situation where something is illegal based on the stated rules and exceptions are made to *allow* something (which is not the case we are dealing with and not what I am asking about). The stated rules do not seem to imply that the purchase has to happen before the sale, and the terms are not defined anywhere so as to imply this seemingly obvious conclusion either. I prefer to base my decisions on facts not on intuitions.

Comment: The authoritative source for determining capital gains is the IRS (see their web site): QUESTION: "How do I figure the cost basis when the shares I'm selling were purchased at various times and at different prices?" ANSWER: "When selling securities, you should be able to identify the specific shares you are selling." What does that mean? YOU CANNOT IDENTIFY WHAT YOU DO NOT OWN at the time of your sale of shares.  IOW, YOU DID NOT OWN THE SECOND LOT OF SHARES PURCHASED. That's reality, no matter how many times you say it's otherwise.

Comment: @braaterAfrikaaner I don't know how else to say this: if this explicit scenario isn't written down, there's nothing we can show you to prove that. You have to use common sense and realize that everything about how capital loss is defined *implies* that what you are asking about cannot be done. The only alternative would be to *try* to claim such a loss, and see what happens. Either the IRS notifies you in writing why it illegal, or you take it to course where a judge makes the obvious interpretation and their ruling is set in writing. *Then* you would finally have your authoritative reference.

Comment: @BobBearker. I'm not sure why you keep replying to this when we've already established this is above your pay grade. "YOU CANNOT IDENTIFY WHAT YOU DO NOT OWN" - This is a demonstrably incorrect assertion (see Monica's comment on Constructive Sale Rule). I would really recommend you don't assume people are intellectually defective and come here to ask questions that can be solved by a trivial answer like yours, that can be found in a two minute google search. If you don't understand why the answer to a question is not obvious, the problem likely stems from your lack of knowledge, not the OP's.